# Positive operator T is invertible iff <Tv,v> is strictly positive

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

To prove that invertibilty implies the inner product is strictly positive.

I am trying to prove it by showing that Tv cannot be orthogonal to v, but can't seem to go anywhere. Any suggestion?

Comment: is this in finitely or infinitely many directions? Do you know the relation between the kernel of an operator and its properties with regard to invertibility (that is in finite dimensions)?

Comment: If you mean kernel = {0}, i do know that. but how does it imply the inner product is strictly positive?

Comment: well, if the map $T$ had a non-trivial kernel, say $Tv = 0$ for $v \neq 0$, what can you say about $\langle Tv, v \rangle$?

Comment: The question is not right， the inner product being strictly positive do not implies the invertiblty. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415382/a-strictly-positive-operator-is-invertible?rq=1

Comment: if Tv = 0 for v $\ne$ 0, then <Tv,v> = 0

Comment: @C.Ding you are absolutely right, that is why I asked whether this was a problem in finite or infinite dimensions (though I realize now that I made a typo). In finite dimensions the above does hold true

Comment: @Harry is $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: It doesn't specify, but let's assume it is

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is positive then the following Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds
$$|\langle Tu,v\rangle |^2\le \langle Tu,u\rangle \langle Tv,v\rangle \quad (*)$$ Assume $\langle Tv,v\rangle =0$ for some $v\neq 0.$ Then substituting $u=Tv$ in $(*)$ implies $Tv=0,$ hence $T$ is not injective.

Conversely assume $T$ is not injective. Then $Tv=0$ for some $v\neq 0.$ In particular $\langle Tv,v\rangle =0.$

When the space $V$ is finite dimensional the injectivity is equivalent to invertibility. For infinite dimension injectivity does not imply invertibility. Therefore a stronger assumption is needed, namely $$\langle Tv,v\rangle \ge c\|v\|^2$$ for a positive constant $c.$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this by using the fact that any positive operator has a unique positive square root.

Let's say that the unique square root is $R$, so $T= R^2=R^*R$ (since $R$ is also positive $R^*=R$.

Thus, $$\forall v\neq 0, \  \langle Tv,v\rangle=\langle Rv,Rv\rangle=\|Rv\|^2>0$$
This implies that $$ v= 0 \iff Rv = 0$$   so $R$ is injective, so $R$ is invertible, and since $$ T=R^2$$
$T$ is indeed invertible.

Even though this proof only proves if T is invertible then $\langle Tv,v\rangle >0$, you can use $T = R^*R$ this trick to solve both directions