# Invertibility of a semi-positive perturbation of identity operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $A$ be (not necessarily bounded) self-adjoint and semi-positive definite operator, i.e., $(x,Ax)\ge 0$ for all $x\in X$. Then does $I+A$ have an inverse? That is, is $(I+A)^{-1}$ well defined? Also, is requiring $A$ to be bounded helpful?

---

I have seen the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415382/a-strictly-positive-operator-is-invertible?rq=1) asked in this comment but without any answer. Personally, I don't know how to approach this question. Could you give me some hints or suggest some reference?

Comment: $\|x\|^2 = (x,x) \le (x,Ax+x) \le \|x\|\|(A+I)x\|$ gives $\|x\| \le \|(A+I)x\|$ for all $x$. So $A+I$ has an inverse, and the inverse is bounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, if $(Ax,x) \ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$, then
$$
           \|x\|^2 \le ((A+I)x,x) \le \|(A+I)x\|\|x\|,\\
                   \|x\| \le \|(A+I)x\|,\;\; x\in\mathcal{D(A)}.
$$
The range of $A+I$ is dense because
$$
            \overline{\mathcal{R}(A+I)} = \mathcal{N}(A+I)^{\perp} = \{0\}^{\perp}= \mathcal{H}.
$$
The derived inequality $\|x\| \le \|(A+I)x\|$ shows that the range of $A+I$ is closed. Indeed, if $y\in \mathcal{H}$, then there exists $\{ x_n \} \subset \mathcal{D}(A)$ such that $\{y_n=(A+I)x_n\}$ converges to $y$. By the derived inequality,
$$
         \|x_n-x_m\| \le \|(A+I)(x_n-x_m)\| = \|y_n-y_m\|,
$$
from which it follows that $\{ x_n \}$ is a Cauchy sequence and, hence, converges to some $x\in\mathcal{H}$. Every selfadjoint $A$ is closed. Therefore, because $x_n, Ax_n$ converge to $x, y-x$, then $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ and $Ax=y-x$ or $(A+I)x=y$. So the range of $A+I$ is closed; because the range of $A+I$ is dense, then $A+I$ is surjective. So $(A+I)^{-1}$ is defined on all of $\mathcal{H}$, and this inverse is bounded because
$$
           \|(A+I)^{-1}y\| \le \|(A+I)(A+I)^{-1}y\|=\|y\|,\;\; y \in\mathcal{H}.
$$
**Note:** The argument above works for unbounded selfadjoint $A : \mathcal{D}(A)\subset \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$. However, a selfadjoint operator defined on all of $\mathcal{H}$ is necessarily bounded, because it is closed.

Comment: So the norm of the inverse is less or equal to $1$?

Comment: @JohnZHANG : Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $A$ is linear and the ground field is $\Bbb C$, then $A$ is self-adjoint.

A must be bounded: Let $x_n \rightarrow x, Ax_n \rightarrow y $,  then for any z $\in H$ we have $<y,z>=\lim<Ax_n,z>=\lim<x_n,Az>=<x,Az>=<Ax,z>$ hence $y=Ax$. By closed graph theorem, A is bounded.

Now $\sigma(A) \subseteq [0,+\infty]$, hence I+A is invertible.

Comment: May I know whether the inverse is bounded?

Comment: @John ZHANG This is from general property of spectrum of semi-positive operator.

Comment: I mean, by invertible, do you mean the inverse is a bounded operator?

Comment: I think if I understand correctly, "$I+A$ is invertible$ means that the inverse is bounded and densely defined on the Hilbert space. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, under the assumption A is defined on the whole space.