# Norm of $(I+A)^{-1}A$ for self-adjoint semi-positive operator $A$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

For a given bounded self-adjoint semi-positive linear operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $X$, i.e. $(Ax,x)\ge 0, \forall x\in X$, I know from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334900/invertibility-of-a-semi-positive-perturbation-of-identity-operator) that $(I+A)^{-1}$ is well-defined with $\|(I+A)^{-1}\|\le 1$. Consequently $(I+A)^{-1}A$ is a bounded operator with $\|(I+A)^{-1}A\|\le \|A\|$.

I was wondering whether we can show $\|(I+A)^{-1}A\|\le 1$. I think the statement holds for finite dimensional cases, and I would like to know whether it holds in general.

---

For finite dimensional case, I think it is OK. By using the eigen-decomposition, I can write $A=UDU^{-1}$ where $U$ is the normalized eigenvectors and $D$ is corresponding (positive or null ) eigenvalues. Then 
$(I+A)^{-1}A=U[(I+D)^{-1}D]U^{-1}$, and each entry of $[(I+D)^{-1}D]$ is non-negative and less that $1$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the continuous functional calculus?

Comment: You can use the spectral theorem of the bounded self-adjoint linear operator. Maybe that is also what @SangchulLee is asking.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes. But I am sorry I am not familiar with that theory.

Comment: @Hans May I know how do you approach the problem by using the spectral theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** This easily follows from the continuous functional calculus. Indeed, since $\sigma(A) \subseteq [0, r]$ for some $r \geq 0$ and $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x} \in C(\sigma(A))$, we have $(I+A)^{-1}A = f(A)$ and

$$ \|f(A)\| = \|f\|_{C(\sigma(A))} \leq f(r) \leq 1. $$

**2.** A direct approach is also available. We begin by noting that both $(I+A)^{-1}$ and $(I+A)^{-1}A$ are positive semi-definite. These, together with a simple identity $(I+A)^{-1}A = I - (I+A)^{-1}$, yield

$$ 0 \leq \langle x, (I+A)^{-1}A x \rangle = \langle x, x \rangle - \langle x, (I + A)^{-1}x \rangle \leq \|x\|^2. $$

This is enough to conclude that $\|(I+A)^{-1}A\| \leq 1$.

Comment: For proof 2., how do you argue $\langle x,Tx\rangle\le\|x\|^2 \implies \|T\|\le 1$ without the spectral decomposition for the bounded self-adjoint operator?

Comment: @Hans, The inequality tells that $\sigma((I+A)^{-1}A) \subseteq [0, 1]$. Then it suffices to note that for a bounded self-adjoint operator $T$, the spectral radius $$\rho(T) = \sup \{ |\lambda| : \lambda \in \sigma(T) \}$$ of $T$ equals the operator norm of $T$. This is an easy consequence of the Gelfand's formula $$ \rho(T) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \|T^k\|^{1/k} $$ combined with the identity $\|T^{2^n}\| = \|T\|^{2^n}$, which follows from $$ \|T^2\| \leq \|T\|^2 = \sup_{x : \|x\| = 1} |\langle Tx, Tx \rangle| = \sup_{x : \|x\| = 1} |\langle x, T^2x \rangle| \leq \|T^2\|. $$

Comment: Thank you. Your functional calculus approach is very elegant.

Comment: May I know how can I prove $(I+A)^{-1}A$ is semi-positive and self-adjoint without using the identity $(I + A)^{-1} A = I - (I + A)^{-1}$?

Comment: @JohnZHANG, Self-adjointness is clear because $A$ and $(I+A)^{-1}$ are self-adjoint and commuting: $$ \langle x, (I+A)^{-1}A x \rangle = \langle x, A(I+A)^{-1} x \rangle = \langle (I+A)^{-1}A x, x \rangle. $$ Next, for each $x \in X$ we can find $y \in X$ for which $x = (I + A)y$. Then $$ \langle x, (I+A)^{-1}A x \rangle = \langle y, A(I+A) y \rangle \geq 0. $$

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following identity:

$$ (I + A)^{-1} A = I - (I + A)^{-1}$$

Comment: My same question as posted below @sangchulLee's answer.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid this identity? It's just a small algebraic step.

Comment: I was not trying to avoid this identity. I actually did the same thing up to the Gelfand formula before you posted your hint but was not sure how to proceed further. Now Sangchul Lee's comment provided the missing step $\|T^2\|=\|T\|^2$ to my derivation.