# Closed range of a strictly positive operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

If  $A$ is a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space such that $A$ is strictly positive. How can we prove that it has a closed Range.

Comment: Is this true? Where do you get this from?

Comment: To prove a strictly positive bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space is invertible, I was proceeding that way. Kindly suggest any counter example if it is not true.

Comment: Why would closed range even imply that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is really about asking if every strictly positive operator is invertible. This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415382/a-strictly-positive-operator-is-invertible) provides a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.